# How to: Import Office 365 emails into Thunderbird

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, office365

I would like to download my emails from Office 365 into my local Thunderbird machine.  I see from here

*I knew POP or IMAP would be my saving grace here but I couldn't find the settings for it anywhere, the UI for the online version of Outlook is... crude. I found them after lots of looking, they're tucked away under a very inconspicuous hyperlink in the settings menu (Your App Settings > Mail). I managed to set up a POP import with a Gmail account.*

I see no where where I can do this.  I have called Godaddy twice they have no support on this.  I have looked on the web multiple times only to see articles that are flat out just wrong.

Anyone else have this issue and a solution?

My provider is Godaddy and they have no support for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not know much about Thunderbird, but you may could try to add your O365 email account as IMAP account in Thunderbird. IMAP access of O365 accounts needs to be enabled by your administrator. Or you might need Outlook desktop client to help transfer your emails in your Office 365 emails to your Gmail account.